# Oracle APEX: Adding single data points/marked positions to a bar chart

Tags: bar-chart, oracle-apex

Does anybody know how to add a single marked position to each bar of a bar chart? I'm new in Oracle APEX and after long research I didn't find a solution. Also the example plots didn't helped with my need. I know I can combine a bar- and a line-chart but I don't want to have a line, just single positions to be marked. The exact representation of the values is not important (points, circles, dashes, stars, ...) but they shouldn't be combined. It could look like this:
[image]

Is there an option in Oracle Apex without changing the source code (I don't have this option)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the type of a line chart to none and activate markers so no lines between the dots were displayed.